# Compile with different optimzation levels for different parts of a code

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I understand that compiling a code with different optimization levels, e.g. `-O2` and `-O3`, can generate different assembly code and consequently cause different performance. For a large project, we often have several third-party libraries, which are often well tested. We normally choose the `Release` type to build the dependencies, i.e. with `-O3` flag. For our newly developed parts, we could use other optimization levels instead of `-O3` for debugging and testing reasons. I am wondering if there are other implications for using different optimzation levels on different parts of a code besides the downgrade of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of correctness, there shouldn't be.  It would be a compiler bug if an optimization level changed the ABI.

It's 100% normal to make test/debug builds at `-O0` or `-Og` and link against optimized libraries (including but not limited to system libraries like libc).

You only need `-O3 -flto -march=native` etc. etc. when testing / optimizing performance.